# Размер шрифта в зависимости от разрешения TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Пользователь может изменять размер формы. В соответствии с этим изменяется и размер TextBox. Можно ли сделать, чтобы шрифт текста в TextBox увеличивался/уменьшался в зависимости от размеров TextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вешаем обработчик на SizeChanged текстбокса.
Код обработчика

```
private void ResizeFont(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    TextTextBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(TextTextBox.Font.FontFamily, TextTextBox.Size.Height * 25 / 100);
}
```